# Ssl connection between gcp load balancer and springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

Currently, I have my web application running on `compute engine` via a `spring boot` application. My website is `ssl` protected and it connects to my `gcp load balancer`. However, the connection between the `load balancer` and my `spring boot application` is `http`. How can I make this `https` as well? What are details that I need to provide. My application is deployed on a gcp compute vm.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I have followed :-

- Generate a Self Signed cert (PKCS12 format) assuming you in development and testing phase else in PROD you will need a CA Signed or similar cert
- Generate Key using your P12 cert and store it in to Key Store

## Make your boot app enabled by setting the following properties

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/yourCertificate.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=yourAlias
# The format used for the keystore. 
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
```

These steps will help you make your Boot app HTTPS enabled.

Comment: @Amit- how do I request a cert with a CA. Can you tell me the details I need to provide. Like I mentioned, my applicaiton is deployed on a gcp compute vm.

Comment: @user3310115 I am not sure what is your role in the company but usually Some one from operations side need to buy it and own and manage it. I am from the development side so not sure about how every thing is transacted. But here is the site that can help.

https://comodosslstore.com/resources/what-is-a-ca-signed-certificate-how-do-i-get-one/

Comment: FYI ... You still can use Self signed cert for your POC but in PROD you will need one signed from an Authority.

Comment: @Amit Google HTTP(S) Load Balancers support self-signed certificates for backend services.